# Is gulp made for fast deployment to remote server using the "dist" directory

Tags: gulp

I have started to learn Gulp. 
It is nice, and now I have a dist folder, which is probably useless if I do not have a straight-forward method to put it on server.

Is there a way that Gulp will handle it for me, taking in concern to upload ONLY those files that modified or newly created? (In order to save upload time, sure).

I am working with Node.js.

Thanks.

Comment: See https://github.com/morris/vinyl-ftp for example.

Answer (score 0):

how do you normally deploy to production? If you use ftp - there is a gulp function for that. If you use AWS S3 - there is a function for that. If you use something like docker or AWS EB, then you will continue to deploy through git etc - there is also likely to be a gulp function for this. Gulp is just a tool to process files and make build/deployment tasks easier.

Pulled straight from gulp website:

> gulp is a toolkit for automating painful or time-consuming tasks in your development workflow, so you can stop messing around and build something.

Comment: I am deploying via FTP. May I let Gulp upload only those files modified or newly created? Plus, delete those file that were deleted from my local project?

Comment: I do not want Gulp do it automatically, I want it only when I decide to set an update - upload the dist folder.